# see anything wrong in this ajax function call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

here is the js

```
$(document).ready(function() {



        $("#quantity").change(function() 
        {
            hash = $("#quantity").val(); //returns 0001 (ex)
            qPrice_price = ajaxCall(hash);
            alert(qPrice_price);
        });






});


    function ajaxCall(hash)
    {
        $.get("ajax.php", { id: hash },

        function(data)
        {
            return parseInt(data.price);

        }, "json");
    }
```

the ajax.php with a url like this: ajax.php?id=0001 returns this   {"price":"5"}
when i select the selection i get an alert of undefined.

this is what the html looks like

```
<select id="quantity" name="quantity">
            <option value="0001">250</option>
            <option value="0002">500</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="0003">1,000</option>
            <option value="0004">2,500</option>
            <option value="0005">5,000</option>
            <option value="0006">10,000</option>
            <option value="0007">20,000</option>
            <option value="0008">30,000</option>
            <option value="0009">40,000</option>
            <option value="0010">50,000</option>
            <option value="0011">100,000</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is alerting undefined because you're not returning anything from your `ajaxCall()` function, nor can you when you're using an asynchronous server call. Your callback function is run after the data is loaded from the server, long after your `alert()` has run. Try alerting *inside* the callback function like this:

```
function ajaxCall(hash)
    {
        $.get("ajax.php", { id: hash },

        function(data)
        {
            alert(parseInt(data.price));

        }, "json");
    }
```

It's also important to note that when you return `parseInt(data.price))`, you're not in the `ajaxCall` scope, so it's not returning anything at all to your alert. There is a way of turning `async` off in jQuery's server calls, but it's not advisable. Instead, as I've done above, think about putting your data handling logic in the callback function.

If you're *dead set* on having a do-it-all AJAX function (though, honestly, this is what jQuery's AJAX functions **are** and there's really no reason at all to do this), you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#quantity").change(function() 
        {
            hash = $("#quantity").val(); //returns 0001 (ex)
            qPrice_price = ajaxCall(hash, handleQuantityChange);
            alert(qPrice_price);
        });
});

function handleQuantityChange(data) {
    alert(data);
}

function ajaxCall(hash, callback) {
    $.get("ajax.php", { id: hash }, function(data) {
        callback(parseInt(data.price));
    }, "json");
}
```

Comment: that kind of defeats what im testing. how can i get it to work? so that i dont have to retype that ajax stuff over and over again for each selection.

Comment: @SarmenHB: How does it defeat what you're testing? The simple fact of the matter is that JavaScript runs synchronously from point A to point B unless you tell it to hang (which will usually freeze the browser) and AJAX calls are asynchronous. Unless you want to cause all kinds of UI headaches, you have to take into account the fact that the data you requested isn't coming back immediately. Also, what's so bad about calling the `$.get()` directly from your initial change event handler?

Answer (score 0):

The callback (`function(data){return parseInt(data.price);}`) is called **when the HTTP response arrives**.

You have to do what you want to do in the callback, you can't return anything from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern instead:

```
    $("#quantity").change(function() 
    {
        var hash = $("#quantity").val(); //returns 0001 (ex)
        $.get("ajax.php", { id: hash },
            function(data)
            {
                doSomething(parseInt(data.price));
            }, "json");
    });
```

If you *insist* on using a separate ajax function which is guaranteed to return a value, you will have to incorporate some *synchronous* yuckery such as this:

```
function ajaxCall(hash)
{
    var rv = null;
    $.ajax({ url: "ajax.php", 
            data: { id: hash },
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data)
            {
                rv = parseInt(data.price);
            }
    });
    return rv;
}
```